# Reading .ini files in Python

Tags: python, ini

I'm new to .ini files I was trying to read .ini Configuration files with python and I'm stuck!
I've tried this methode, but it didn't really worked for me:

class iniConfig:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.iniConfig = ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
    try:
        f = open('C://Desktop//PythonScripts//Config.ini', 'r')
        self.iniConfig.read(f)
        print("Sections: ", self.iniConfig.sections())

    except OSError:
        print('File cannot be opened!')
```

The Output:

```
     Sections: []
```

I still don't get what I'm doing wrong :(

Thank you in advance,

3301

Comment: The line f = open('The_Path_to_ini', 'r') is not meaningful here. What is 'The_Path_to_ini'?

Comment: Create an ini file in the standard format and save it as `The_Path_to_ini`. But if I were you, I'd change it to a more meaningful file name.

Comment: I've already created an ini file and I've even changed the whole code but the problem was never solved.

Comment: You appear to completely miss the most important point. *Is it actually called `The_Path_to_ini`?* **That** is the filename that your code is trying to open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the actual path to your .ini file instead of `'The_Path_to_ini'` at these lines:

```py
    f = open('The_Path_to_ini', 'r')
    print(self.iniConfig.read('The_Path_to_ini'))
```

It may also be a good idea to handle an exception that may occur in `open` call. According [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) documentation:

```
If the file cannot be opened, an OSError is raised.
```

You can handle this exception using `try ... except` block by this way:

```py
try:
   f = open('file', 'r')
   ...
except OSError as e:
   print('File cannot be opened: ', e)
```

It is common to use `with` statement instead of `try ... except` blocks if you don't need to handle exceptions. For example:

```py
with open('file', 'r') as f:
   # work with f
```

Read more about with statement in Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).

Comment: It is the command  self.iniConfig.read('The_Path_to_ini') that attempts to load the ini-file. The open function is not needed

Comment: Hey, thanks for your replay but I'm still getting the OSError even when I put the absolute path to the .ini file.

Comment: Thanks, I added `self.iniConfig.read()` to my answer. We don't know why `open` function is used, I assume that information about exception handling could be useful.

Comment: @3301 does your user have enough rights to open this file? Check this from the command line: `stat -c %G:%A <filepath>`.

Comment: I do have permission to open files (I hope so). I've tried all above mentioned solutions but nothing worked for me :((

Comment: Even without the try: except: block I'll get an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a file with open, and using .read that accepts a path, so try this instead:

```
   def __init__(self):
      self.iniConfig = ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
      try:
          self.iniConfig.read('C://Desktop//PythonScripts//Config.ini')
          print("Sections: ", self.iniConfig.sections())

      except OSError:
          print('File cannot be opened!')
```